# Editorfor template complaining about data type, not sure how to solve

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, mvc-editor-templates, editorfor

I have a Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ADate { get; set; }
}
```

When I go to create a product, obviously the fields are going to be empty but I still want to set my create.cshtml has type Product:

```
@model WebApplication.Domain.Entities.Product
```

So now this is done in my create.cshtml, I start to write the form for it and add an editor for my ADate property..

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADate, "DateTime" )
```

which in turn is using an editor template:

```
@model System.DateTime

@Html.TextBox(
   string.Empty, 
   Model.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
   new { @class="datepicker", @type = "date"})
```

but when I do this, it complains on runtime:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.
```

What do I need to do in my

- model,
- create.cshtml or
- DateTime.cshtml

to stop it complaining when the data is empty...

**------------EDIT---------------**

I ended up doing this in my DateTime.cshtml:
does this look okay?

```
@model System.DateTime?

@if( Model.HasValue )
{ 
    @Html.TextBox(
        string.Empty, 
        Model.Value,
        new { @class="date", @type = "date"})
}
else
{ 
    @Html.TextBox(
        string.Empty, 
        null,
        new { @class="date", @type = "date"})
}
```

Comment: You could change the model in the editor template to `DateTime?` (nullable)..

Comment: but then the ToString method fails. I guess I just wrap an if statement in the editor template for that part right?

Comment: When you call `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADate, "DateTime")` is your model null?

Comment: ..`ToString` will only fail because it will need to be changed to `Model.Value.ToString()`... you should check for `null` in the editortemplate too.

Comment: It says "Nullable object must have a value."